# JSON vs JSON Array in .NET Web API - Bandwidth V2

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json, api

I am converting an existing application to consume JSON via POST from Bandwidth's V2 SDK for .NET.  I'm not well-versed in either C# or JSON.

The previous version simply sent a JSON string like so:

```
{
"type"          : "message-delivered",
"time"          : "2016-09-14T18:20:16Z",
"description"   : "Message delivered to carrier",
"to"            : "+12345678902",
"message"       : {
  "id"            : "14762070468292kw2fuqty55yp2b2",
  "time"          : "2016-09-14T18:20:16Z",
  "to"            : [
      "+12345678902",
      "+12345678903"
    ],
  "from"          : "+12345678901",
  "text"          : "",
  "applicationId" : "93de2206-9669-4e07-948d-329f4b722ee2",
  "owner"         : "+12345678902",
  "direction"     : "in",
  "segmentCount"  : 1
   }
}
```

And I could add it to my db like so:

```
// POST api/values
public HttpStatusCode Post([FromBody] CallbackEvent callback)
{
     recCallback.Add(new tblCallback { Type = response, MessageID = callback.Message.Id, Description = callback.Description, MessageTo = callback.To, SegmentCount = callback.Message.SegmentCount });
     callbacks.SaveChanges();
 }
```

In version 2, it is wrapping the JSON response in [] - an array.   Although they are still only passing a single callback, they are making it an array for future purposes.

I don't know how to reference this array so I might iterate through it.   The CallbackEvent class is as follows:

```
//     Catapult Api callback event
public class CallbackEvent
{
    public CallbackEvent();

    public CallbackEventType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public IncomingMessage Message { get; set; }
    public string ReplyTo { get; set; }
    public int SegmentCount { get; set; }

    //     Parse callback eevent data from JSON
    public static CallbackEvent[] CreateFromJson(string json);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just have your v2 controller take an array of `CallbackEvent`?

Comment: I don't know how to make an array of CallbackEvent.

Comment: check out the answer posted by Austin T French. That's what I was suggesting you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should have to do is change the controller signature:

```
// POST api/values
public HttpStatusCode Post([FromBody] List<CallbackEvent> callback)
{
   //...
}
```

the .net deserializer should make this trivial. And then loop through the list (preferably in a business layer of some sort):

```
// POST api/values
public HttpStatusCode Post([FromBody] List<CallbackEvent> callback)
{
     foreach(var message in callback)
     {
        recCallback.Add(new tblCallback { Type = response, MessageID = 
             message.Message.Id, Description = message.Description, MessageTo = 
             message.To, SegmentCount = message.Message.SegmentCount });            
     }
     callbacks.SaveChanges();  // <-- Not sure of the context for this, but appears to be a dbContext and should be saved when done with List<T>
 }
```

Comment: @Ben no reason to be embarrassed. Auto-magical black boxes are usually the hardest get at first, precisely because there isn't code saying `if (body.Params.GetType() == typeof(List<MyClass>)`